# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List ErroR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I get the following error here:

```
        Line 45:         <tr>
        Line 46:             <td width="15%" valign="top">
        Line 47:                 @{Html.RenderAction("GetMenu","RoomType");}
        Line 48:             </td>
        Line 49:             <td valign="top"


 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type   
 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LicentaTest.Models.RoomType]'.
```

I dont know where i am wrong .this is my GetMenu method from RoomTypecontroller:

```
      'public ActionResult GetMenu()
        {
        DBContext.Current.Open();
        var model =RoomType.SelectAll();
        DBContext.Current.Close();
        return PartialView(model);
         }'
```

And here is my Get menu view:

```
      @model IEnumerable<LicentaTest.Models.RoomType>
      @using LicentaTest.Models
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
      $("#categories").addClass("ui-widget");
      $("a", "#categories").button().width(200);
      });
      </script>
      <ul id="categories">
      @foreach (var tipcamera in Model) 
      { 
<li>@Html.ActionLink(tipcamera.Room_Type,"Browse","RoomType",new{RoomType=tipcamera.Room_Type},null)
       </li>


        }
```

Comment: what is the return type of RoomType.SelectAll()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i don't know what your `RoomType.SelectAll()` do but i suppose that it return a `List<object>` any way try this it should work:

```
var model = RoomType.SelectAll().Cast<RoomType>();
```